# pd.Series to pd.DataFrame while multiplying each element with each other element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, math

Assuming I have a vector of the form `| a | b | c | d |`, e.g.

```
vec = pd.Series([0.3,0.2,0.2,0.3])
```

What's a quick and elegant way to build a `pd.DataFrame` of the form:

```
| a*a | a*b | a*c | a*d |
| b*a | b*b | b*c | b*d |
| c*a | c*b | c*c | c*d |
| d*a | d*b | d*c | d*d |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy broadcasting:

```
vec = pd.Series([0.3,0.2,0.2,0.3])

a = vec.to_numpy()

df = pd.DataFrame(a * a[:, None], index=vec.index, columns=vec.index)
print (df)
      0     1     2     3
0  0.09  0.06  0.06  0.09
1  0.06  0.04  0.04  0.06
2  0.06  0.04  0.04  0.06
3  0.09  0.06  0.06  0.09
```

Or [`numpy.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.outer(vec, vec), index=vec.index, columns=vec.index)
print (df)
      0     1     2     3
0  0.09  0.06  0.06  0.09
1  0.06  0.04  0.04  0.06
2  0.06  0.04  0.04  0.06
3  0.09  0.06  0.06  0.09
```

**Performance** (if is important like mentioned @enke in comments):

```
np.random.seed(2022)
vec = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10000))

print (vec)


In [39]: %%timeit
    ...: fr = vec.to_frame()
    ...: out = fr.dot(fr.T)
    ...: 
386 ms ± 13.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [40]: %%timeit
    ...: pd.DataFrame(np.outer(vec, vec), index=vec.index, columns=vec.index)
    ...: 
    ...: 
351 ms ± 2.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [41]: %%timeit
    ...: a = vec.to_numpy()
    ...: 
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame(a * a[:, None], index=vec.index, columns=vec.index)
    ...: 
293 ms ± 4.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted to avoid NumPy as it will remove the index of my series but I can reassign it. `np.outer` appears to do exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @Stücke - do you need index='a,b,c,d' and columns `a,b,c,d` ?

Comment: My series has a "custom" index. I can simply do `df.index = vec.index` and `df.columns =vec.index`.

Comment: @Stücke - You can also use `pd.DataFrame(np.outer(vec, vec), index=vec.index, columns=vec.index)`

Comment: I see. Nice move to put it into the df creation ... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `dot`:

```
fr = vec.to_frame()
out = fr.dot(fr.T)
```

Output:

```
      0     1     2     3
0  0.09  0.06  0.06  0.09
1  0.06  0.04  0.04  0.06
2  0.06  0.04  0.04  0.06
3  0.09  0.06  0.06  0.09
```

Comment: Actually, I like this answer because it retains the index of the vector!

Comment: @Stücke yeah, this is nice and short but the numpy solution is more efficient than this one (if you care about it).

Comment: Ok, got it thanks!